# How do I identify negative group speeds?

Tags: finite-difference, hyperbolic-pde, wave-propagation

This question is a continuation of [one of my other questions](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/40664/a-simple-wave-for-the-linear-shallow-water-equations).
I've been trying to show that collocated (non-staggered) grids can suffer from negative group speeds in the linearized shallow water system. I do this by solving the equations for a simple, right-traveling wave crest, so that any left-traveling component can be identified as having negative group-speed. For my initial conditions I use a Gaussian wave profile with initial velocities $u_0(x) = h_0(x)\sqrt{g/h_0(x)}$.

My wave indeed moves in the right direction, but I have trouble with the interpretation. To the left of the crest, a trough appears with a small bump in the middle. This trough moves to the left. I see the same thing on a staggered grid. I can't spot a clear difference between the staggered and the non-staggered grid and I can't see negative group speed.

Is this trough normal? How can I identify the negative group speeds?

[image: snapshot from the non-staggered grid solution]

EDIT:
A comment suggests that I split the wave up into modes and calculate the speed of the modes separately. I'm not really familiar with such decompositions in practice, so I used the discrete fourier transform from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59725933/plot-fft-as-a-set-of-sine-waves-in-python). I use $2\pi$freqs as the wavenumbers, but I'm not sure if that's correct? If I then use this function on a snapshot of the wave and plug my "wavenumbers" into the formula for the group speed (according to the discretization scheme), I get the following:

[image: groupspeeds]

I like this because the group speeds on the staggered grid are non-negative. Does this look right? Also, since I'm using the formula for the group speed, does that not make this exercise a circular reasoning? Because even when the numerical solution is exactly the same on both grids, my computation of the group speeds would still get me a different result on both grids.

Comment: You need to decompose your wave into individual modes, and compute the speed for each mode separately. In linear models, the modes are typically sine or cosine waves.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I thought about your suggestion. See the edit I made to my post.

Comment: I think you may have a bug in your implementation. If you refine in space and time, does the left-going part tend to zero?  It should, rather quickly. 

Aside from a bug, the peft-going part is likely to be the result of using a multistep time discretization. You can avoid it by writing the wave equation in first-order form and applying a Runge-Kutta method in time.